# Preventing multiple form submittions with validation

Tags: javascript, html

Could someone please help me in locating where i need to place this code below into my validation script.

The script works great, but users are clicking more than once and the form is sending multiple times.

I tried including the code just below the `if(valid)` line but still does not work.

This is the code i am trying to include:

```
form.submit.disabled = true;
form.submit.value = "Please wait...";
```

This is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e){
    $("#nominateForm").on('submit',(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var valid;  
        valid = validateContact();
        if(valid) {
            $.ajax({
            url: "contact_mail.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data){
            $("#mail-status").html(data);
            },
            error: function(){}             

            });
        }
    }));

    function validateContact() {
        var valid = true;   
        $(".nominateForm").css('background-color','');
        $(".info").html('');

        if(!$("#nominate-name").val()) {
            $("#nominateName-error").html("Please enter a name of who you would like to nominate");
            valid = false;
        }

        return valid;
    }

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: It looks like you could add those two lines of code to disable the submit button right after `e.preventDefault();` in your onsubmit logic; have you tried that?

Comment: you could disable the submit button `disabled="disabled"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put those two lins inside the `if` condition and after the success call, you should turn them back into the default values. Also the correct way of accessing the properties of your submit button is like below,

```
$('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
$('input[type="submit"]').prop('value', 'Please wait...');
```

or if it has an `id` equal to `mySubmitBtn`

```
$('#mySubmitBtn').prop('disabled', true);
$('#mySubmitBtn').prop('value', 'Please wait...');
```

So your code should be,

```
if(valid) {
    $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('input[type="submit"]').prop('value', 'Please wait...');
    $.ajax({
    url: "contact_mail.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:  new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    success: function(data){
        $("#mail-status").html(data);
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('value', 'Submit');
    },
    error: function(){}             
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi chayasan, your solution was the only one that worked for me. exactly how you displayed the full code. i assume the mySubmitBtn would be if i used different id's on the input tags?

Comment: Glad it worked! :) Yes, `mySubmitBtn` should be changed to match your own id. If the answer worked you can mark it as accepted. :) If you need further help I will change my solution.

Comment: Happy to help you! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an HTML element showing something like 'processing' and if it is processing, then skip the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (e){
        $("#nominateForm").on('submit',(function(e){
            var status = document.getElementById('someHTMLElement');
            if (status.innerHTML != 'processing') {
                 status.innerHTML = 'processing';
                 e.preventDefault();
                 var valid;  
                 valid = validateContact();
                 if(valid) {
                     $.ajax({
                     url: "contact_mail.php",
                     type: "POST",
                     data:  new FormData(this),
                     contentType: false,
                     cache: false,
                     processData:false,
                     success: function(data){
                     $("#mail-status").html(data);
                     },
                     error: function(){}             

                     });
                 }
                 status.innerHTML = '';
            }
        }));

        function validateContact() {
            var valid = true;   
            $(".nominateForm").css('background-color','');
            $(".info").html('');

            if(!$("#nominate-name").val()) {
                $("#nominateName-error").html("Please enter a name of who you would like to nominate");
                valid = false;
            }

            return valid;
        }

        });
        </script>
```